# Pass stdout of child to parents stdin

Tags: c, fork, pipe, stdout, stdin

I try to pass the stdout of an program in a child process to the stdin in the parents process.

In bash this would look like this:

wget "adress"|less

My code looks like this:

```
    int fd[2];
    pid_t child_id;
    int status;
    char *args[] = {"wget","-O -",argv[1], NULL};
    int pipe(int fd[2]);

    child_id = fork();
    if (child_id == -1)
    {
        printf ("Fork error\n");
    }
    if (child_id == 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]); 
        int c = dup2(fd[1],1);
        execl ("/usr/bin/wget", "wget", "-qO-",argv[1], NULL);
    }
    else{
        waitpid(child_id,&status,0);
        close(fd[1]);
        int c2 = dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        printf("%i\n",c2 ); //debugging
        execl ("/usr/bin/less", "less", NULL);
    }
```

Please note that argv[1] should be an webadress.
But when running the program the debug output of the dup2 (`int c2 = dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);`) in the parent returns -1 - so it fails.

I can't find the programm.

Comment: Not sure if that is the answer but won't using a pipe-special file help in this case?

Comment: As a side note, you might be interested in `popen()`.

Comment: I know there is way without redirecting the stdin/out but I want to do it like this

Comment: did you check `errno` to see why dup2 failed?

Comment: You do not want the `waitpid`.  If the child has to write more data than will fit in the pipe, it will block on a write and never terminate.  Just skip the `waitpid` and let the two run concurrently.  (Although you shouldn't allow the child to become an orphan, you cannot `wait` for it before you process its output)

Comment: Note that `less` does not expect to have any children when it starts, so the best(?) way to let the parent become `less` and avoid any potential orphans is to double-fork the child.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: shouldn't `wget` be killed by SIGPIPE if `less` dies i.e., `wget` will be an orphan only until it tries to write something to the pipe?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  If the less is killed, the expected behavior would be for `wget` to get a SIGPIPE when it overflows the buffer, but `less` won't terminate until it is interrupted.  However, it is bad behavior to rely on SIGPIPE, since many processes get run with SIGPIPE ignored (eg, under the subprocess module in python 2.4 (I believe that was the version with the bug)  Definitely safer not to rely on the SIGPIPE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not call `pipe(2)` in your program. I guess, your

```
int pipe(int fd[2]);
```

should be

```
pipe(fd);
```

Comment: In deed! What a dumb fault - Thank U!