# Easy way to abandon children on exec

Tags: unix, exec

Is there a simple, standard way to abandon all children before `exec`ing a new process image?  Similar to setting a file descriptor to close on exec, it would be nice to make all your children be adopted by init.  You can ignore SIGCHLD which would (on some platforms) give a partial solution to the problem raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230838/pass-stdout-of-child-to-parents-stdin#comment30171946_20230838), but that's certainly not portable.  I don't really see a use case for this behavior, but I'm curious to know if there is a standard mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

That's an very interesting question.

While the signal handlers themselves are set back to intelligent defaults when you `exec` (and I think pending signals are cleared), you are still that same process ID (PID) in the hierarchy so you will still *own* the children that are running.

That means that future SIGCHLD signals will find their way to you as those children exit.

One way to avoid this is to, rather than `exec`, perform a sneaky switcheroo. By that, I mean, `fork` first, then have the parent process simply exit (so the current children are adopted by `init`).

The child process resulting from the `fork` has a totally different PID so has only a sibling relationship with the other children at that point. It can `exec` your new program and carry on, safe in the knowledge it is childless.

Comment: SIG_IGN is typically retained across the exec, but can easily be reset.  But some platforms apparently have differing semantics when SIGCHLD is ignored.  I believe there are some platforms in which the child is a child of `init` immediately after the fork rather than a child of the process doing the fork.